# The correlation coefficient of two random variables

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables

I would need to know how to show that the correlation coefficient of two linearly dependent random variables is $\pm1$.

All I know so far is the correlation factor formula, but I didn't really understand how it works, since I didn't get a good explanation about it in class.

I know only

$$R_{xy}=\frac{\text{Cov}\left(x,y\right)}{\sqrt{\text{Var}\left(x\right)}\cdot\sqrt{\text{Var}\left(y\right)}}$$

Comment: What is your definition of linearly dependent random variables?

Comment: The statement is not **quite** true.  Actually the correlation coefficient is either $\pm 1$ or undefined, the latter being the case where at least one of the random variables is constant or has infinite variance.

Comment: @RobertIsrael now that I got a better understanding I agree that your remark is correct, but that's just how the question was written so... :( 
Thanks for your precious remark

Answer (score 1):

I actually found the solution to this and some other questions I needed clarification here http://people.math.gatech.edu/~ecroot/3225/rho_notes.pdf

Hope this helps you guys